# SwiftUI: Views with different ToolbarItem placement cause app crash

Tags: swiftui

I get an application crash when using views with different ToolbarItem placements. Below is a code snippet that allows you to reproduce the crash.

**Behavior**

I use 3 views, each with its own defined toolbar. `homeView` and `profileView` have the same toolbar structure. They each use a ToolbarItem with a `.bottomBar` placement. The `addView` on the other hand has a ToolbarItem in the toolbar placed on the action `.cancellationAction'.

When a ToolbarItem is pressed, the `viewState` in the ViewModel is changed. This results in a change of the currently displayed view.

**Error Msg:**

`[error] precondition failure: invalid attribute id: 70981 AttributeGraph precondition failure: invalid attribute id: 70981.`

**Target**

iPhone X 14.0 (18A373)

**Code snippet:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct SomeView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView() {
            content
        }
    }
    
    private var content: AnyView {
        switch(viewModel.viewState) {
        case .home: return AnyView(homeView());
        case .add: return AnyView(addView());
        case .profile: return AnyView(profileView());
        }
    }
    
    func homeView() -> some View {
        Text("Home View")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                    HStack {
                        Button("Home", action: { viewModel.setViewState(state: .home) })
                        Button("Add", action: { viewModel.setViewState(state: .add) })
                        Button("Profile", action: { viewModel.setViewState(state: .profile) })
                    }
                }
            }
    }
    
    func addView() -> some View {
        Text("Add View")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .cancellationAction) {
                    Button("Cancel", action: { viewModel.setViewState(state: .home)})
                }
            }
    }
    
    func profileView() -> some View {
        Text("Profile View")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                    HStack {
                        Button("Home", action: { viewModel.setViewState(state: .home) })
                        Button("Add", action: { viewModel.setViewState(state: .add) })
                        Button("Profile", action: { viewModel.setViewState(state: .profile) })
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}

// MARK: View Model

extension SomeView {
    class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var viewState: ViewState
        
        enum ViewState {
            case home, add, profile
        }
        
        init() {
            self.viewState = .home
        }
        
        func setViewState(state: ViewState) {
            self.viewState = state;
        }
    }
}

// MARK: Preview

struct SomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SomeView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it looks like a bug to me.

A possible workaround is to put every view in a separate `NavigationView`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        content
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    var content: some View {
        switch viewModel.viewState {
        case .home: NavigationView { homeView() }
        case .add: NavigationView { addView() }
        case .profile: NavigationView { profileView() }
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can add the bottomBar to the `addView`:

```
func addView() -> some View {
    Text("Add View")
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .cancellationAction) {
                Button("Cancel", action: { viewModel.setViewState(state: .profile) })
            }
            ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                Text("")
            }
        }
}
```

or just display the `addView` as a `sheet`.